# WSO2 - Unable to deploy synapse import:{org.wso2.carbon.connector}XXX. Required library not found

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

I get this error when I try to use external connector on wso2 studio 7: `Unable to deploy synapse import:{org.wso2.carbon.connector}XXX. Required library not found.`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if repository/deployment/server/synapse-libs is created and if it contains zip file of your connnector. if not then create this folder and copy your zip file.